# PHP password_verify not matching hash

Tags: php, hash, password-encryption

So I have two functions for registering and logging in. Registering works fine, the user table is populated, the hash is stored in the user_pass column etc. When logging in, I keep getting the "Wrong Details" error message. It seems the password_verify isn't matching the hash with the inputted password. Can you guys see anything wrong with my code? I'm scratching my head here....

```
public function register($uname,$umail,$upass)
{
    try
    {
        $new_password = password_hash($upass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO users(user_name,user_email,user_pass) 
                                                   VALUES(:uname, :umail, :upass)");

        $stmt->bindparam(":uname", $uname);
        $stmt->bindparam(":umail", $umail);
        $stmt->bindparam(":upass", $new_password);                                        

        $stmt->execute();   

        return $stmt;   
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }               
}


public function doLogin($uname,$umail,$upass)
{
    try
    {
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT user_id, user_name, user_email, user_pass FROM users WHERE user_name=:uname OR user_email=:umail ");
        $stmt->execute(array(':uname'=>$uname, ':umail'=>$umail));
        $userRow=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        if($stmt->rowCount() == 1)
        {
            if(password_verify($upass, $userRow['user_pass']))
            {
                $_SESSION['user_session'] = $userRow['user_id'];
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you verified the results of the hash are the same that is being stored in DB and returned?  `var_dump()` the return results of `password_hash()` and the `user_pass` column and compare.

Comment: I var_dump the $new_password and it's string(60) "$2y$10$Ygo1AXF4shTgslmTbLqSeeS0fOAU0Yy3.hX/X4.BBjJEYrUfa9h9S"  then I checked the database column and it's $2y$10$Ygo1AXF4shTgslmTbLqSeeS0fOAU0Yy3.hX/X4.BBjJEYrUfa9h9S

Comment: Have you verified, that `$stmt->fetch()` actually returns you the record you're thinking of? Doing `var_dump($userRow)` can be really helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rowCount()` does not return the number of rows in a `SELECT` statement. There is no need to test to see if the query succeeded, you can move right to testing the password:

```
public function doLogin($uname,$umail,$upass)
{
    try
    {
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT user_id, user_name, user_email, user_pass FROM users WHERE user_name=:uname OR user_email=:umail ");
        $stmt->execute(array(':uname'=>$uname, ':umail'=>$umail));
        $userRow=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        if(password_verify($upass, $userRow['user_pass']))
        {
            $_SESSION['user_session'] = $userRow['user_id'];
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }

    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually it is not a safe operation do proceed without checking the data. First of all - there's no verification, that more than 1 record was retrieved - which is a confusing situation for the presented algorithm, as it is not clear which user the author needs to log in. Second - when no records are retrieved, then there will be access of `FALSE['user_pass']` - which results in warning of error (except when framework is a crappy one an just silences that). There should be at lease `if ($userRow)` check present.

Comment: It's kind of a mixed bag on whether this is safe or not @AndreyTserkus If no rows an error will be thrown. If the OP is making sure the table contains unique values, which he should, then there will never be more than one row in the `users` table with the ID in question. We cannot write all of their code for them, but thanks for the DV - I'll take what you have said under consideration when answering this question again down the road.

Comment: Well, the check there was on purpose. So the right suggestion would be to advice a right function to use, not to just delete the incorrect one.

Comment: We'll have to agree to disagree @AndreyTserkus. None of the systems I have ever participated in ever performed that check save for the olden days of the MySQL API. It is an unnecessary check that does not need replacing as the query (against a properly setup database as I mentioned before) will either return results, or it will not. The OP has handled that with a `return false;`

Comment: The issue is not just with proper DB. There are two cases not checked - 0 records and 2 records retrieved. First case - 0 records - PHP is going to generate warning every time, when it tries to access FALSE['user_pass']. And the OP will either have logs filled with warnings, or will silence that behavior, which is against best practices. Second case - 2 records - Imagine users ("Emily Vans", "evans@a.edu") and ("Ed Vans", "evans@gmail.com"), and this function receives the args ("Emily Vans", "evans@gmail.com") - pretty valid case with a correct DB. But whom will func authenticate? Not clear

Comment: If the username or the email (or both) have a `UNIQUE` constraint in the database your example still does not cause a problem @AndreyTserkus

Comment: Jay, create a table with any unique indexes you'd like to. Insert there two records I provided - they will be inserted. Create the PHP function you proposed and call it with the arguments I provided. Check the number of the results returned - there will be 2 records. And, of course, there's another case of 0 records - it should be answered too ;)

Comment: What is your selection criteria?

Comment: It's not mine, it's OP's and yours ;) The whole SELECT query is in the function you posted.

Comment: Right, and it selects a singular value. The form being used sends a username and email address from which one or the other is queried. You cannot select for both values you provided because once the first condition is satisfied the query is complete. A short test against a database containing your criteria satisfied that test. We're not issuing a blanket query against the database.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to continue. I'm done with this thread.